# How to write a function result to instance variable

Tags: dart

I have an error in 5 line

> *The instance member
> 'generateId' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the
> reference to the instance member with a different expression*

what i shoud do to write a function result to instance variable?

```dart
import 'dart:math';


class User{
  int id = generateId(10); // error i here
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String eMail;
  String password;
  final DateTime regDate = DateTime.now();

  User(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.eMail, this.password,){
    id = generateId(10);
  }
  
  @override
  String toString() =>'User: \n$firstName \n$lastName';

  int generateId(int count){
    int result;
    List <int> nums = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      nums.add((Random().nextInt(9) + 1).toInt());
    }
    result = int.parse(nums.join());
    return result;
  }
}





void main() {
  User newUser = User("D", "P", "example@ex.com", "password");

  print(newUser);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `generateId` method `static`.

The method does not need access to the object, it uses no instance methods or fields, so it can, and should, be declared `static`.

(It can also be significantly simplified.)

```dart
static int generateId(int count){
  var result = 0;
  var random = Random();
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result = result * 10 + random.nextInt(9) + 1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Also consider whether you really need all digits to be non-zero, or you just need the first digit to be non-zero. If so, you can do:

```dart
 final int id = 1000000000 + Random().nextInt(9000000000);
```

to get a random ten-digit identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you have only a single constructor and that sets the id anyway, you can basically remove it:

This:

```
int id = generateId(10); // error i here
```

becomes:

```
late int id;
```

Done.

In case your really, really need that line, you could make the generateId method either a function instead of a class method, or you could make it static. That should work, too.

Comment: Most of the fields of this class should probably be `final`. By making `id` late, it will have a setter *even* if it's final. I generally recommend not making any public API member `late` (unless the class is only used by yourself, then you're the only one it affects).